# UMASK not having effect on some file creations

Tags: linux, files, permissions

I have `umask` set to `002` in my Linux server and its working fine while I create file using `touch`. But I still have some files that are created with permission contrary to `umask`. These problematic files are created as a result of a script that is scheduled via `cron`; they have `-rw-r-----` permissions but they should have `-rw-rw-r--` according to `umask` set to `002`. Is there any other factor that controls permission other than `umask`?

The OS is SunOS usdyda01 5.10 Generic_150400-14 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5220

Comment: SunOS usdyda01 5.10 Generic_150400-14 sun4v sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5220 are the OS details..

Answer (score 2):

The `umask` set in your session does not affect `cron`. (In fact, each session could have a different `umask`.) You would need to set the `umask` at the beginning of your script executed by `cron`.